# Таблицы в редакторе MarkDown. Перевод термина GitHub-flavored markdown

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, markdown

В редакторе Markdown появилась поддержка таблиц. Необходимо перевести строки, связанные с ней.

Возникает вопрос, как лучше перевести такой термин, как GitHub-flavored markdown, например:

> Create tables using the GitHub-flavored markdown format

Это расширенный синтаксис markdown, который используется на GitHub и многих других сайтах. Как лучше сформулировать?

---

По результатам обсуждения предложил:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15675

```
**Создавайте таблицы, используя [формат GitHub-flavored markdown]($gfmUrl$)**
```

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15631

```
Поддержка таблиц у нас основана на спецификации [расширенного синтаксиса таблиц GitHub-flavored markdown]($gitHubHelpUrl$).
```

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15673

```
Вы можете создавать таблицы, используя [формат GitHub-flavored markdown]($gfmUrl$).
```

Comment: Что-то типа "диалект Markdown от GitHub"

Comment: Может, что-то в духе, "используя тот же синтаксис, что и на GitHub"?

Comment: Зачем вообще переводить GitHub-flavored markdown?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Предлагаю не переводить:

> GitHub Flavored Markdown

Это название [спецификации](https://github.github.com/gfm/) (которая, кстати, лицензирована под [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)).
Без перевода её будет легче найти.

Answer (score -2):

Создавайте таблицы с помощью маркдауна Github'а.

Answer (score -3):

Создавайте таблицы так же, как на GitHub'е.